# Validação de formulário em tempo real com php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, websocket

Supondo que eu tenho um formulário com alguns campos, e um desses campos é um campo de CPF.

```
<input name="cpf" 
       data-input-mask="cpf" 
       data-input-field="cpf"  
       data-input-validator="cpf" 
       value="" 
       class="form-control input-field" 
       type="text">
```

Atualmente, pelo meu framework, eu identifico o `'input-mask'` no evento jQuery `keyup` e `focus`, adiciono a mascara, e também, a cada modificação no dado do input faço uma solicitação para um caller em php, que faz a validação de acordo com `'input-validator'`, a resposta dessa validação é um JSON contendo `'true'` ou `'false'` e um código da mensagem de erro, algo como `'0546'`, mensagem que está armazenada num arquivo JSON.

Esse método funcionou bem por um tempo, porém, as coisas começaram a ficar mais extensas e os formulários mais complexos, fazendo com que o desempenho caia muito devida a quantidade de requisições.

Com algumas pesquisas encontrei coisas como:

WebSocket.

Plugin jQuery validator (pessoalmente achei horrível).

Validar com JAVA (?) (Não fez muito sentido pra mim JAVA + PHP, mas foi indicado por um amigo programador)

Validar com javascript puro (É o modo mais fácil, mas cai em eu não poder reaproveitar meus métodos PHP).

No modo que eu utilizo, os métodos de validação em PHP das requisições ajax de cada input são as mesmas aproveitadas após a submissão do formulário.

Qual é a melhor opção (sem sair do jQuery + PHP) pra validar campos, entre outras features como atualização de gráficos em tempo real ?

Se, requisições ajax cronometradas(ou disparadas), como melhorar o desempenho das mesmas ?

Se webSocket, não sei absolutamente nada sobre, qual framework/pacote/plugin PHP me fornece um documentação boa ? (Tentei usar o cboden/ratchet porém sem sucesso).

Se outro modo, qual seria recomendado pra uma aplicação que raramente terá mais do que 20 acessos simultâneos e possui um servidor dedicado?

PS: O problema das muitas requisições ajax atuais estão mais client-side do que server-side.

Comment: Provavelmente seu amigo disse JAVA(script), existe uma diferença entre java e javascript :)

Comment: Não vejo pq validar por ajax ou websocket. Faz a validação em javascript e confere no PHP de novo por segurança.

Comment: @MarceloBoni Eu sei que não é a mesma coisa, ele disse JAVA mesmo, mas provavelmente isso foi um mal entendido de informação.

Comment: @KarlZillner É isso que eu estou tentando entender qual fica melhor, considero pelas requisições ajax para mais fácil, pois no PHP ja tenho tudo pronto e não queria ter de refazer todos os validadores em outra linguagem.

Comment: O ideal no seu caso, já que acredito que seu servidor roda php, é caso necessário fazer uma validação superficial em javascript, e depois que os dados passarem pro backend continuar fazendo a validação com php

Comment: Websocket para validação é uma má ideia. O melhor é fazer em js mesmo. Já que vai ter de fazer algo novo, não daria para abstrair as regras de maneira que possam ser usadas tanto por um código php quanto por um js?

Comment: Geralmente, a tudo que se diz "em tempo real" leva a entender o uso de ajax *Asynchronous Javascript and XML*, ou seja, a validação é feita, sem ser necessário dar um refresh na página, talvez ai tenha iniciado a confusão

Comment: @bfavaretto Até teria como, mais existem algumas validações complexas, como validação de código de barra, cpf válido, cnpj, algumas com relação a comparação de datas e compensação de valores, não sei se com meu conhecimento em JS eu conseguiria ter o mesmo resultado que tenho com PHP, mas pelo visto acho que mudar pra JS vai ser o jeito.

Comment: @MarceloBoni provavelmente irei fazer isso mesmo, validação leve com js, e com php o mais pesado e validações de segurança.

Comment: Provavelmente vc já tem isso escrito na internet em javascript. Não precisará reescrever tudo.